# The equivalent of ASM classes (Java) in C#

Tags: java, c#

I've been tasked with converting a project, whilst upgrading it, to C# from Java.

However, I'm finding issues with the following classes and their features:

```
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.AbstractInsnNode;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.FieldInsnNode;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodInsnNode;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode;
```

The class I'm working with in Java is attempting to read .jar files and their contents (classes). However, I haven't been able to find any equivalent classes/features in C#, including JavApi.

Is there any possible way I can recreate this in C#? Could the Java docs help me?

Comment: These seems to be development kit classes, if these classes are in .dll, you can try to load it to your project, and also you can inspect them and write your own classes in c#, also as your project is working with .jar files that are specific Java executables, I think it is a bad idea to convert project to .net.

Comment: I am not aware of the full capabilities of ASM, depending on what you need to do you can load an assembly and inspect it using reflection. You can also read the IL code of methods using mono.reflection https://github.com/jbevain/mono.reflection. If you want to create classes you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Quoting from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectWeb_ASM): the ASM library 'provides a simple API for decomposing, modifying, and recomposing binary Java classes (i.e. bytecode).' Which makes me think: if you want to keep manipulating Java classes, your best bet is to stay with Java (because manipulating Java classes in .NET simply does not make sense, at least not to me). However, if you suddenly want to manipulate .NET assemblies instead, you will be in for a complete rewrite, given that the .NET CLR will probably not use the same commands and concepts.

Comment: I'm still wanting to manipulate JAR files despite the framework being used. The user wishes, for reasons I really don't know, that I do this in C#. Ideally I would be staying with Java but unfortunately I don't think that's possible for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into using IKVM (http://www.ikvm.net) to use the Java classes, as otherwise you would likely have to recreate ASM's functionality in C# from scratch.